# How to configure fastlane to use an existing enterprise certificate for signing iOS (ionic) app

Tags: fastlane

I couldn't find a solution and I spent several days trying to configure fastlane to use an existing enterprise distribution certificate to sign an iOS app. The app is written in Ionic Framework.

Please share how you DID it, either native iOS app, Ionic etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use Fastlane `gym` for this purpose to build and sign your app.

**1.)** Make sure you've added the enterprise **certificate** (.cer) and it's **private key** (.p12) into the Keychain Access app on your Mac, and the certificate is not expired.

The certificate should be in the `login keychain`, you can filter for the `My Certificates` to show it.

**2.)** First, make sure that you can do an archive and you're able to sign it with Xcode:

Set `Generic iOS Device` then go Product > Archive. After the archive is created, select `Distribute App` > `Enterprise` > `Automatically manage signing` > ...

If this fails, it will fail with Fastlane, too. It's important to check that you can distribute the app in Xcode, first. It might happen that you have some kind of problem with the Provisioning Profiles and your problem is not related to Fastlane at all.

**3.)** Finally, in the `Fastfile`, implement something like this:

```
lane :archive_enterprise do
    gym scheme: 'Scheme name',
        configuration: 'Release',
        export_method: 'enterprise',
        clean: true
end
```

**4.)** Execute with `fastlane archive_enterprise` in Terminal.